# error in delivering static content in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, static

I have the following app.yaml configuration file:

```
- url: /privacy.html 
  static_files: html/privacy.html
  upload: static_files
  
- url: /terms.html 
  static_files: html/terms.html
  upload: static_files
```

While hitting www.samplewebsite.com/privacy.html from the web browser, it complains the following:

```
Error: Not Found

The requested URL /privacy.html was not found on this server.
```

Everything works fine in local dev server.

Comment: Did you get any messages when uploading your app? You need to change your configuration to upload: html/privacy.html, and upload: html/terms.html. Also the second url should be url: /terms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as Sebastian Kreft pointed out your "upload:" clause is wrong. Read his comment to figure out what it should be.